# DB lock on DLFileRank

Tags: locking, liferay-6

After connecting to a new lportal schama, our DBA informed me that my connection is causing a lock on DLFileRank table , the query that causes the lock is : `delete from DLFileRank where fileRankId=:1` , I tried after some recommendation to add the following to `portal-ext.properties` in the sdk folder : `dl.file.rank.enabled=false` , but it didn't help .... any advice ?
I am using liferay 6.1 and oracle 12g DB

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue in my environment. Did you ever track down root cause of this?

Comment: unfortunately no , the project is already delivered and till now I have no idea what was the issue :)